# How to convert array to string within an ajax function

Tags: sql, arrays, ajax, function, parsing

```
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/configuration/v2/bbr-knowledgebase-drug-data",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {search_drug: search_drug},
                success: function (response){
                    var tbody="";
                    $.each(response.all_drugs, function (key, drug) {
                    tbody+='<tr>'+
                                '<td class="p-1">'+drug.drug_name+'</td>'+
                                '<td class="p-1">'+drug.drug_code+'</td>'+
                                '<td class="p-1"><p class="font-weight-bold m-0">Dosage:</p>'+drug.dosage_list+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                    });

                    $('tbody').html(tbody)
                }
            });
```

Currently, the line `drug.dosage_list` is an array, there are quotes and brackets which I need to take out:

[image: 1]

How do I convert it into string while it is an ajax function at the same time? adding `+toString(drug.dosage_list)+` gives an object undefined error

also to clarify: `$.each(response.all_drugs, function (key, drug)` all_drugs is taken form an SQL SELECT statement

Comment: How is this related to the <sql> _language_?

Comment: `$.each(response.all_drugs, function (key, drug) ` all_drugs is taken form an SQL SELECT statement